# SSL certificate not working in Chrome/Edge but it does in Firefox/GET in Postman

Tags: asp.net-core, google-chrome, ssl, kestrel-http-server

I'm trying to add ssl to my locally run .NET 7 API using Kestrel. I use a wildcard certificate from an official CA with the CN and SAN *.mycompany.com. I load the certificate from a .pfx file, which contains the wildcard, and intermediate certificate and the root certificate.

This is how I set up the server:

```
.UseKestrel(
                    options =>
                    {
                        var lovCertificate = CertificateManager.GetCertificateFromFile("wildcard.mycompany.com2024");
                        
                       
                        options.AddServerHeader = false;
                        
                        options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5001, listenOptions =>
                        {
                            listenOptions.UseConnectionLogging();
                            listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
                            if (lovCertificate != null) listenOptions.UseHttps(httpsOptions =>
                            {
                                httpsOptions.ServerCertificateSelector = (context, dnsName) =>
                                {
                                    return CertificateManager.GetCertificateFromFile("wildcard.mycompany.com2024");
                                };
                            });
                        });
                    }
                    )
                    //.UseUrls("https://" + "log.mycompany.com" + ":5001")
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

I linked 127.0.0.1 and localhost to the domain log.mycompany.com using the Windows hosts file.

When I go to https://localhost:5001 in Chrome, I get the usual warning screen which I expected to happen with the error:

> NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

And when I go to https://log.mycompany.com:5001 the warning screen doesn't appear. but the green lock still doesn't show and when I click the information button it says:

> Your connection to this site is not secure.

On edge it even says that there is no certificate provided.

I don't get why there doesn't even appear a warning or a specific error message like when the domain name doesn't match the SAN of the certificate.

In Firefox it works perfectly fine and I can see the entire trust chain as valid. In Postman, when making requests to the url, it works fine as well and it also shows the certificate as trusted.

Answer (score 0):

My web server didn't return a webpage. Apparently Chrome doesn't show a valid https connection when receiving a 404. After adding Swagger I could confirm that the certificate was valid.